# Save pdf generated by html2pdf on my project folder ,im using flask server not downloads folder if not send it to telegram automatically

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to save pdf inside my project server if not send the generated pdf automatically to telegram i have token_id and chat_id both working

```
function createPDF() {
          var element = document.getElementById('contenido');
          html2pdf(element, {
              margin:1,
              padding:0,
              filename: 'myfile.pdf',
              image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
              html2canvas: { scale: 2,  logging: true },
              jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'A2', orientation: 'P' },
              class: createPDF
          })

type here
```

i tried weasyprint ,jspdf gave me pdf file that has dark baclground ,html2pdf generated the file but i wasn't able to send that file to telegram or store it inside  project folder like my flask project.`function createPDF() { var element = document.getElementById('contenido'); html2pdf(element, { margin:1, padding:0, filename: 'myfile.pdf', image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 }, html2canvas: { scale: 2,  logging: true }, jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'A2', orientation: 'P' }, class: createPDF })`

Comment: I'd recommend iText7 for either C# or Java, it works pretty good for HTML conversions with a little modifications to how you setup the CSS